# iPhone: CGBitmapContextCreateImage() only works in Simulator

Tags: iphone, image, ios-simulator, cgimage

I created an app which creates an image by using CoreGraphics. The images appears on the screen when using the iPhone Simulator (OS 3.1 beta3) but not when I run the application on the device. What could be the cause of this?

The code snipped which extracts the image from the context and puts it in an image view looks like this:

```
    ...
    ImageResultViewController *resultViewController = [[ImageResultViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    // Extract resulting image from context
    UIImage *renderedImage = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)] retain];
    [resultViewController presentImage:renderedImage];
    [renderedImage release];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:resultViewController animated:YES];
    [resultViewController release];
    CGContextRelease(context);
```

Thanks in advance!

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Aaah, this took me a long time. It was the old issue that the simulator is case-insensitive when loading from resource files (images, ...) and the device is not.
So when your file is named *myImage.png*, the simulator will load it when you name it *myImage.PNG* but iPhone will not.